# hadoop distributed file system wordcount example

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop

```
public class WordCount {

   public static class Map extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
     private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
     private Text word = new Text();

     public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
       String line = value.toString();
       StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);
       while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
         word.set(tokenizer.nextToken());
         output.collect(word, one);
       }
     }
   }

   public static class Reduce extends MapReduceBase implements Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {
     public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<IntWritable> values, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
       int sum = 0;
       while (values.hasNext()) {
         sum += values.next().get();
       }
       output.collect(key, new IntWritable(sum));
     }
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

     JobConf conf = new JobConf(WordCount.class);
     conf.setJobName("wordcount");

     conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
     conf.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

     conf.setMapperClass(Map.class);
     conf.setCombinerClass(Reduce.class);
     conf.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);

     conf.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class);
     conf.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);

     FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path(args[0]));
     FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(args[1]));

     JobClient.runJob(conf);
     }
}
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
at org.myorg.WordCount.main(WordCount.java:64)
```

i am noob in hadoop plz help me

Comment: Please grab a book about Java first, this isn't a Hadoop problem at all.

Comment: What command did you use to run this program...?

Answer (score 1):

It means you haven't run your program with any commandline arguments, if you would check args.length you would see it is zero, so run the command with an input/ and an output/ specification..